# SQL Files in Git becomes binary or unreadable

Tags: sql-server, git

We have a problem when we commit files to a git repository.
We only have a problem MS SQL (Transact) files that has the file ending .sql. Sometimes they are transfered up to the git repository as binary files and are thus hard to impossible to use.
Some files have a control character between every real character.
Example:

select becomes s?e?l?e?c?t?

[image: Text]

We have tried hard to overcome this problem with .gitattributes where we tried UTF-16 and UTF-8 settings, but we still have some trouble remaining.
Today, after several attempts we have the following situation:

Coder 1: has the code in perfect shape on his computer, no problem at all, but when he pushes his changes to BitBucket the code is ruined.

BitBucket: has the code with control characters between every character.

Coder 2: has the code pulled from BitBucket and it has chinese (?????) characters in it when I open it in Visual Studio Code.

[image: Text]

We cannot get it to work?!!?

Both the pictures above is the same code. Sorry for the images it was hard to convey any other way.

Comment: This is not related to the SQL _language_, so I removed the <sql> tag.

Comment: @jarlh I thought people with knowledge about SQL might also have encountered the problem that's why I included it. But I have no problem that you removed it.

Comment: You could perhaps add the <sql-server> tag?

Comment: If your team is using SSMS have you all standardised on the same setting for Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension > sql : SQL Query Editor with Encoding? If you're all using VS Code it shouldn't matter - it should be defaulting to UTF-8 already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely problem here is that the file is being saved in UTF-16 of some sort.  This encoding, and specifically the little-endian variant, is popular on Windows, but practically nowhere else, and is generally being used less in favor of UTF-8, which [has many advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Comparison_with_other_encodings).

UTF-16 has two possible endiannesses: big-endian and little-endian.  It *should* always be written preceded by a byte-order mark (U+FEFF), but, if it is not, the standard says that it is big endian.  Many Windows programs ignore this specification, and write it in little-endian format, which is broken.  It is also possible to write a specific endianness without a byte-order mark, in which case this is a different encoding, either UTF-16-LE or UTF-16-BE.

The first image is what you'll see if you try to render a UTF-16 file as UTF-8.  UTF-16 text in the ASCII range contains many NUL bytes (those with value zero) and will lead to that rendering.  It's possible the second one is due to a mismatch on the endianness of the data, but it's hard to tell from the image.

If and only if this file must be in UTF-16 to work, you can set `*.sql working-tree-encoding=UTF-16` for it in `.gitattributes`.  *However*, if you do that, everyone will have it checked out to UTF-16 and everyone will need to save it as UTF-16.  Users can also set this on a per-repository basis by writing an equivalent line in `.git/info/attributes`.

However, the best solution is to just mandate that everyone use UTF-8 and set up your CI system to reject text files with NUL bytes.  You should also require that people use the form without a BOM because a BOM is not necessary or desired with UTF-8, and reject text files that start with the bytes 0xef 0xbb 0xbf.  All modern editors should be capable of this setting, and it should be the default for any editor that works cross platform, since it is nearly universal on Unix systems and on the Web.  Users who still want to use something else can still set that value in `.git/info/attributes`, but everyone will need to check in UTF-8.  This is how Git is intended to work.

To fix these files, you may want to try `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8`, possibly replacing `UTF-16` with `UTF-16-LE` or `UTF-16-BE`, as appropriate.

If you have Perl available in your CI system, implementing the checks I suggested is as simple as `perl -0777 -ne 'exit 1 if /\0|\xef\xbb\xbf/'`, appending any relevant filenames to the end of the command line.